# Appending latest message from websocket using redux-saga while receving and sending latest message

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-hooks, mqtt, redux-saga

I have connected a web socket through redux saga. It successfully connected through out whole app. But while receiving and sending latest message I am getting notification of that corresponding message. But I am unable to bind it in UI.

Here is my socket connection file

```js
import {take, put, call, fork, select} from 'redux-saga/effects'
import {eventChannel} from '@redux-saga/core'
import mqtt from 'mqtt'
import publish from './publish'
import unsubscribe from './unsubrcibe'
import messagepublish from './messagepublish'
import {parseMessageType} from '../constants/parseMessageType'
import {mergeArrays} from '../constants/config'
import {notification} from 'antd'
import {displayListMessage} from '../constants/displayListMessage'
import Avatar from 'antd/lib/avatar/avatar'

const userdetail = state =>
  state.auth.loginMessage || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('logindetails'))

const messageDet = state => state.message.messageList || []

function connect() {
  let options = {
    protocol: 'wss',
    clientId: '',
    username: 'inextrix',
    password: 'inextrix',
  }
  const client = mqtt.connect('wss://ee.astppbilling.org:9001/wss', options)
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    client.on('connect', () => {
      resolve(client)
    })
  })
}

function* read(client) {
  const loguserdetail = yield select(userdetail)
  client.subscribe(
    [
      `GetChats/${loguserdetail.user_id.user_id}`,
      `GetMessages/${loguserdetail.user_id.user_id}`,
      `Message/${loguserdetail.user_id.user_id}`,
    ],
    {qos: 1},
    err => {
      if (err) {
        return
      }
    }
  )
  const channel = yield call(subscribe, client)
  let action = yield take(channel)
  yield put(action)
}

function* subscribe(client) {
  const loguserdetail = yield select(userdetail)
  const mesdet = yield select(messageDet)
  return new eventChannel(emit => {
    const chatdata = (topic, message) => {
      switch (topic) {
        case `GetChats/${loguserdetail.user_id.user_id}`:
          return emit({
            type: 'GET_CHAT_LIST_SUCCESS',
            payload: JSON.parse(new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(message)),
          })
        case `GetMessages/${loguserdetail.user_id.user_id}`:
          return emit({
            type: 'RECEIVE_MESSAGE_SUCCESS',
            payload: JSON.parse(new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(message))
              .messages,
          })
        case `Message/${loguserdetail.user_id.user_id}`:
          let newreceivermessage = parseMessageType(
            JSON.parse(new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(message)),
            false,
            false,
            false
          )
          notification.info({
            message: newreceivermessage.name,
            description: displayListMessage(
              newreceivermessage.type,
              newreceivermessage.payload
            ),
            icon:
              newreceivermessage.userImage !== '' ? (
                <Avatar src={newreceivermessage.userImage} shape="square" />
              ) : (
                <Avatar
                  src={newreceivermessage?.name?.charAt(0)}
                  shape="square"
                />
              ),
            placement: 'topRight',
          })
          return emit({
            type: 'ADD_MESSAGE_SUCCESS',
            payload: newreceivermessage,
          })
        default:
          return emit({
            type: 'MQTT_CONNECT_SUCCESS',
            payload: {
              topic,
              message: JSON.parse(new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(message)),
            },
          })
      }
    }
    client.on('message', chatdata)
    return () => {}
  })
}

export default function* flow() {
  yield take('MQTT_CONNECT')
  const client = yield call(connect)
  yield fork(read, client)
  yield fork(publish, client)
  yield fork(messagepublish, client)
  yield fork(unsubscribe, client)
}
```

Here I am Sending Message through socket while chatting this will concat the newmessage to existing array

```js
import {take, call, put, fork, select} from 'redux-saga/effects'
import {parseMessageType} from '../constants/parseMessageType'

export default function* messagepublish(client) {
  const {payload} = yield take('ADD_MESSAGE')
  client.publish(
    payload.topic,
    JSON.stringify(payload.message),
    {qos: 1},
    err => {
      if (err) {
        return
      }
    }
  )
  let newreceivermessage = parseMessageType(
    JSON.stringify(payload.message),
    false,
    false,
    false
  )
  yield put({type: 'ADD_MESSAGE_SUCCESS', payload: newreceivermessage})
}
```

The list of Messages which are displaying according to design of sender and receiver in UI. I want to display the concat message in this screen without refreshing or going back

```js
import React, {useEffect, useMemo} from 'react'
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import {MQttSendMessage, MQttConnect} from '../../../redux/action/actions'
import {displayMessage} from '../../../redux/constants/displayMessage'
import '../../../App.css'

const ChatBody = props => {
  const usercred = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('logindetails'))
  useEffect(() => {
    const chatbody = {
      chatId: props?.chatdetail?.chatId,
      opponentUid: props?.chatdetail?.senderId,
      secretId: '',
      dtime: -1,
      messages: props.messageList,
    }
    props.MQttSendMessage('GetMessages', chatbody)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div style={{height: '93vh'}}>
      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={props?.messageList?.length}
        className={'chat-body-list'}
        inverse={true}
        hasMore={true}
      >
        {props.messageList.map((v, i) => (
          <div
            key={v.messageId}
            style={{
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent:
                v.senderId === usercred?.user_id?.user_id
                  ? 'flex-end'
                  : 'flex-start',
              margin: 3,
            }}
          >
            {displayMessage(v, usercred?.user_id?.user_id)}
          </div>
        ))}
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
  )
}

function initMapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    messageList: state.message.messageList,
  }
}
function initMapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      MQttSendMessage,
      MQttConnect,
    },
    dispatch
  )
}

export default connect(initMapStateToProps, initMapDispatchToProps)(ChatBody)
```

I have also message reducer which contain old message as well as new message action

```js
const initialState = {
  messageList: [],
  messageErr: '',
  mesageLoading: false,
}

export default (state = initialState, {type, payload}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'RECEIVE_MESSAGE_SUCCESS':
      return {
        messageList: payload,
        messageErr: '',
        mesageLoading: false,
      }
    case 'RECEIVE_MESSAGE_ERROR':
      return {
        messageList: [],
        messageErr: payload,
        mesageLoading: false,
      }
    case 'RECEIVE_MESSAGE_LOADING':
      return {
        messageList: [],
        messageErr: '',
        mesageLoading: true,
      }
    case 'ADD_MESSAGE_SUCCESS':
      return {
        messageList: state.messageList.concat(payload),
        messageErr: '',
        messageLoading: false,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me How can I acheive it

Comment: Can you be more precise with which part you struggle with? That's a lot of code to go through... Also how often/when is the `flow` saga executed? Is it just once on app start or for every single request? Because right now you are always reading only a single message from the server.

Comment: I am struggling to binding latest message from websocket server in ui. I am able to display latest message in web notification but not able to display it in UI.

Comment: @MartinKadlec my flow saga is executed on every single request

Comment: Creating a new connection for every request seems very inefficient. Regardless, since you are still very vague about where exactly the problem is, I'd start with simple debugging - Do you get the "Message" with new message in the event channel? If so, does it get in correct form to reducer? if so, does your component rerender and has the correct new data in `messageList` prop?

Comment: Yes I am getting new message from the event channel. It also get in correct form to reducer but it does not rerender